# Is there a finitely additive measure on R which is not sigma-additive?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the usual measurable space of real number $( \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
My question is:

Is there an application $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}( \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ such that :

i) $\mu$ is finitely additive

ii) $\mu( \mathbb{R}) < \infty$

iii) $\exists (A_n) \subset \mathcal{B}( \mathbb{R}) $ that:

a) $ A_n \subset A_m \forall n<m $

b)
 $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n) < \mu( \cup_{n} A_n)$

Comment: Maybe this might be useful for you: [Example for fintely additive but not countably additive probability measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204842) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204842)).

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Take a non-principal ultrafiler $\omega$ on $\mathbb{N}$, and define $\mu$ as follows:

$\mu(A)=0$ if $A\cap\mathbb{N}$ does not belong to $\omega$,

$\mu(A)=1$ if $A\cap \mathbb{N}$ belongs to $\omega$.

This measure if finitely additive, and if $A_n=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, then $\mu(A_n)=0$ for every $n$, while $\mu(\bigcup A_n)=\mu(\mathbb{N})=1$.

Comment: On the side of plain existence, we may also argue: since $c_0$ is not reflexive, neither is its dual $\ell_1$, meaning there are bounded additive, non $\sigma$-additive measures on $\mathbb{N}$ (signed, but then also positive)